# SELECT union of results from same subquery in MySQL

Tags: mysql, join, subquery, union, lateral-join

Say I have a query which looks something like this:

```
select step0.a, step1.a, step2.a
from (select id from tbl1) as step
inner join tbl1 as step0 on step0.id = step.id
left join tbl1 as step1 on step1.b = step0.a
left join tbl1 as step2 on step2.b = step1.a
```

This works fine. Now, say I want to union these results with the reverse of `a` and `b`, i.e.:

```
select * from (
(
select step0.a, step1.a, step2.a
from (select id from tbl1) as step
inner join tbl1 as step0 on step0.id = step.id
left join tbl1 as step1 on step1.b = step0.a
left join tbl1 as step2 on step2.b = step1.a
)
union (
select step0.b, step1.b, step2.b
from (select id from tbl1) as step
inner join tbl1 as step0 on step0.id = step.id
left join tbl1 as step1 on step1.a = step0.b
left join tbl1 as step2 on step2.a = step1.b
)
) rows
```

This also works fine. But notice that the `select id from tbl1` subquery is duplicated.

The question I have, is how do I store the results of this subquery, without using temporary tables, such that each `select` in the union can reference it?

Comment: please update  your question add  a proper data sample you actual result and you expected  result

Comment: You don't. Just do what you're doing.

Comment: @scaisEdge I don't have a problem getting the data I want, I just want to eliminate subquery duplication.
@Strawberry what if the subquery is significantly longer and more complex than the simple `select id from tbl1` in the example?

Comment: MySQL 8.0 now supports [`With` clause](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/with.html), for common table expressions.